# Grant Select on All VIEWS [current and future] in Schema X

Tags: oracle, view, privileges

I have a situation in our Oracle environment where I would like to be able to grant select permissions to a certain user/group on all views in a particular schema.

I realize that I could write a dynamic statement to iterate over all the views in the schema and grant permissions to them individually as shown [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/842689) but I would like to be able to have this apply to all views that exist in the schema now or in the future.

I was also contemplating the possibility of writing a [DDL trigger](http://psoug.org/reference/ddl_trigger.html) that could monitor for the creation of new views but setting permissions in a trigger isn't something I've seen done before and doesn't seem like accepted practice.

Basically, is there a **VIEW** analog to the **GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE` grant allows a user to execute any procedure in any schema in the database, not just those in a particular schema.  You can grant a user the `SELECT ANY TABLE` privilege-- that will allow the user to query any table or view in any schema in the database not just those in a particular schema.  That's the analogous privilege, it just seems unlikely that either is really what you're after.

Since views should not be created dynamically, this sort of requirement would normally be handled by simply including the appropriate `GRANT` statements in the scripts that create the new views which get promoted up through the environments.  Dynamically granting privileges is generally frowned upon because it generally implies that you have issues with your change control process that need to be addressed.

I have, for third party applications that insist on creating new objects periodically, created a [DDL trigger that grants privileges on new objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262539/how-do-i-create-a-oracle-trigger-that-grants-permissions).  In order to do that, you would need to submit a job that actually does the `GRANT`.  A `GRANT` is a DDL statement so it issues an implicit commit and implicit commits aren't allowed in triggers, you have to have a separate job that runs moments after the object is created.  This means that you end up with a number of moving pieces that generally makes your environment more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Justin. The desire to do this is specifically due to the fragmented nature of change management. I was hoping that it would be possible to simply setup a role that would always have select permissions on all views in Schema X for currently existing views and any created in the future. Based on your answer and continued research I take it that this is not possible.

Comment: @Carth - Correct, there is no simple way to do this sort of thing.  You would ideally need to deal with the fragmented nature of change management.  Barring that, the DDL trigger approach works reasonably well, it just makes the environment a bit more complicated and can make change management harder to detangle if the trigger does something different in different environments.