# In Oracle 11g, what permissions would I need to `SELECT * FROM V$TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM;`?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, permissions, permission-denied, aws-dms

I am using AWS DMS to migrate an on-site Oracle 11g database to an Amazon RDS for Oracle DB instance of the same major version. I recently received this error:

```
2019-11-27T18:54:08 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: Cannot execute SQL statement 'select tp.endian_format, tp.platform_name from v$database d, v$transportable_platform tp where d.platform_id = tp.platform_id'. OCI status '-1' [1020401] (oradcdc_redoutil.c:976)
2019-11-27T18:54:08 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: OCI error 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'; Cannot execute SQL statement 'select tp.endian_format, tp.platform_name from v$database d, v$transportable_platform tp where d.platform_id = tp.platform_id'. OCI status '-1'; Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_XGQVEPQ6RSAXZT44XOZF7ERABI ; Stream component 's
```

My normal administrative schema can `SELECT * FROM V$TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM;` without issue, however, my new 'migration' schema cannot. Both have `SELECT ANY TABLE` privileges which, as described in [Grant Select on All VIEWS [current and future] in Schema X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729145/grant-select-on-all-views-current-and-future-in-schema-x), will allow the user to query any table or view in any schema in the database.

What permission am I missing in my migration schema? How does `V$TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM` differ from table/view objects in the database? What query could I run in order to obtain the type of `V$TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM` or any other database object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you may want to try:

- Grant `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` to allow SELECT on system views
- Add a manual GRANT to `V_$TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM` since `V$TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM` will reference that table
- Ensure the schema is not ambiguous by adding `SYS.`

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. It sounds like this object is a data dictionary and not a table or view. Is that right? From searching the role you suggested I found the following two links, which helped describe the role: (1. http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_dbazine_ault_cross_plat.htm, 2. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_dictionary_select_any_dictionary_and_select_catalog_role.htm); I'll attempt adding the role to see if this resolves my problem. I see now my administrative schema grants `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`. How would I have found that this is a data dictionary if I didn't already know this?

Comment: It's still a view, it's just special since it is a system one that gives you special insight into the database itself.  If you have a standard user that you want to allow to see all views and tables, you might intend just user-generated tables.  Anything that is sys/system maintained will require different privileges from day to day user created schemas because of that cohesion with its internals.
A catalog/data dictionary is just something you learn as you go, just like undo & redo, rollback, replication, optimizer hints, etc., etc.  The Oracle docs has a trove of info.